# help with understanding this terminology re dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a book called Applied Mathematics: Body and Soul, that was recommended to me by a lecturer.

I'm reading the section about the scalar (dot) product of two vectors and in the book it says:

"we may summarise by saying that the scalar product a .b = f(a,b) is a bilinear symmetric positive definite form on R2 * R2.

this book has a consistently confusing way of explaining concepts and despite knowing how to take the dot product of vectors already, I still kinda want to understand what they mean by bilinear symmetric positive definite form on R2 * R2.

If anyone knows how to explain what that means in simpler terms, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space. For example, $V$ could be $\mathbb{R}^2$, the set of all vectors in the plane.

A *bilinear form* on $V$ is a function $f(x,y)$ that takes two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $V$ as arguments and returns a real number as a value, and that satisfies certain additional algebraic properties. These are:

1. $f(x + x',y) = f(x,y) + f(x',y)$
2. $f(cx,y) = cf(x,y)$
3. $f(x,y + y') = f(x,y) + f(x,y')$
4. $f(x,cy) = cf(x,y)$

The function defined by $f(x,y) = x \cdot y$ satisfies all of these properties, since we have the formulas $(x + x') \cdot y = x \cdot y + x' \cdot y$, $(cx) \cdot y = c(x \cdot y)$, $x \cdot (y + y') = x \cdot y + x \cdot y'$, $x \cdot (cy) = c(x \cdot y)$.

We say a bilinear form $f(x,y)$ is *symmetric* if

5. $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$.

This is true of the dot product since $x \cdot y = y \cdot x$. Note that if property 5 holds, then we need not state 3 and 4 separately, since they then follow from 1 and 2.

Finally, we say a symmetric bilinear form $f(x,y)$ is *positive definite* to mean that

6. $f(x,x) > 0$ whenever $x \ne 0$.

That is true of the dot product because $x \cdot x > 0$ whenever $x$ is a nonzero vector.